# Is mass per surface area / gravity a constant?

Tags: gravity

While playing with an online calculator for planetary parameters I found I was consistently getting 1.17E+10 kg/m^2 making a surface gravity of 1g.  This seems to hold anywhere from degenerate mass (note: Newtonian calculations) to a sparse gas and scales linearly with surface gravity.

Is this actually a constant and does the distribution of the mass matter?  (Do I get the same surface gravity if the mass is concentrated in a shell rather than a ball of basically uniform density like a planet?)

The first result was a total surprise, my understanding is that the arrangement of the mass doesn't matter but the whole thing is so counter-intuitive I feel I must be getting something wrong.

Comment: i think considering Gauss's Law regarding inverse-square fields might be elucidating.

Comment: Each unit of mass (kg) is a source. Consider these all constantly emit "gravity beams". If there is a constant area to pass through (m^2), then the flux will be constant. I guess the non-trivial insight is that the "gravity beam" density (flux) is related to gravitational field by a simple constant.

Comment: @AlanRominger There are two factors at work: You're getting farther away and there's more mass off to the side also pulling.  Apparently they cancel each other out but I don't see how your answer is related to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surface area is $A=4\cdot \pi \cdot  r^2$, so the distance in terms of the area is $r = \sqrt{A/4/\pi }$

Because $g=G\cdot m/r^2$ it follows that $g=4 \cdot \pi \cdot G \cdot m/A$ which means that the mass must increase by the same factor as the area in you want the same gravitational force on the surface.

For the second part of your question see [Newton's shell theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_theorem): if the mass inside the sphere is distributed spherically symmetric it does not matter if it is distibuted evenly or concentrated as point in the middle of the shell.

Comment: I guess the units add up,  it just feels wrong.  As the sphere gets bigger there's far more mass off to the sides.  It seems strange that that exactly cancels the effect of being farther away.

Comment: Newton proved it and Einstein accepted it, and if you integrate the whole thing you will get the same result.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Integrating the gravitational contribution from a spherically symmetric mass distributions (i.e. proving the shell theorem) is typically done (or given as a problem) in detail in a junior level mechanics or E&M class. It is much more tedious than difficult once you have the right tools.